# Xcode 12 - Dependency cycle inside project when Objective-C code uses Swift classes

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, circular-dependency

I have a project mainly written in Swift that uses some legacy Objective-C code, which, in turn, needs to use some Swift classes. I tried to add some Unit Tests but I started having issues with the bridging header and Xcode complained about dependency cycles. I've been able to create a toy project showing similar issues. The toy project is available on GitHub: https://github.com/AndreaCogliati/ObjCTesting/tree/main/ObjCTesting

I started by creating `SwiftClass`, then I added `ObjCClass`, finally I used `ObjCClass` in the `ViewController`. At this point the project would build and run. However, if I try to add a simple Unit Test, I get the following error:

```
error: Cycle inside ObjCTesting; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'ObjCTesting' has compile command for Swift source files
○ Target 'ObjCTesting': Ditto /Users/andreac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjCTesting-daonzuzybyfxwnaugjkgfuplyrbj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ObjCTesting.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjCTesting.build/DerivedSources/ObjCTesting-Swift.h /Users/andreac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObjCTesting-daonzuzybyfxwnaugjkgfuplyrbj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ObjCTesting.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjCTesting.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ObjCTesting-Swift.h
○ Target 'ObjCTesting' has compile command for Swift source files
```

I tried to follow the troubleshooting steps on Apple Documentation at https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev621201fb0 but none of the listed causes seem to apply here.

Also, if I clean the Build Folder, I get a different error: `failed to emit precompiled header ... for bridging header ObjCTesting-Bridging-Header.h`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @MartinVandzura unfortunately, no.

Comment: I was able to solve it. Error happens when you import "target-swift.h" into objective c but some of you Swift classes use objective c. So it's cycle.

 Instead if importing "target-swift.h" you need to add class directly to .h file @class SwiftClassName